# Build Dependent Maven Project On Github Action

Tags: maven, github-actions

I have a project like that (https://github.com/senolatac/hexagonal-architecture-demo/tree/core-dependency) I try to create a simple github-action test step with github action.

On my project, there is a dependency like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sha</groupId>
    <artifactId>sha-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

And the github link is here: https://github.com/senolatac/sha-core

Here, I try to build main project with github action like that:

```
  - uses: actions/checkout@v4
    with:
      ref: main
      token: ${{ secrets.ACCESS_TOKEN }}
      #ssh-key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
      repository: senolatac/sha-core

  - name: Build project with Maven
    run: mvn -B package --file pom.xml

  - uses: actions/checkout@v4
  - name: Build project with Maven
    run: mvn -B package --file pom.xml
```

So it is like, build sub project then build main project but it gives error: `Could not find artifact com.sha:sha-core:jar:0.0.1 in central`

Is there a way to handle it with github action?

Comment: You have to create a multi module build where one part is the spring boot part and another part which contains the `core` part. That means you can build everything in one go...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Checkout base project and install it to local repository.
2. Checkout the project and compile it.

Solved like that:

```
name: Main
on: [push]

jobs:
  build_test:
    name: Build and Test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Set up JDK 17
        uses: actions/setup-java@v4
        with:
          distribution: 'zulu'
          java-version: 17

      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          ref: main
          ssh-key: ${{ secrets.PRIVATE_SSH_KEY }}
          repository: senolatac/sha-core

      - name: Install core project with Maven
        run: |
          mvn -B install --file pom.xml

      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Build project with Maven
        run: |
          mvn compile
          mvn -B package --file pom.xml
```